# Função Javascript para troca de cores

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou desenvolvendo uma função para customização de cores de um template para pessoa ter liberdade para customizar do jeito que quiser. Criei uma função JS para isso, ela funcionou perfeitamente quando se tratou de apenas uma palheta de cores. Quando inseri a segunda palheta de cores, a  segunda palheta não funciona.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function(){
         var palheta = document.getElementById('palheta');
         var tds = palheta.getElementsByClassName('td1');
          var palheta2 = document.getElementById('palheta2');
          var tds2 = palheta2.getElementsByClassName('td2');

      /* for para primeira palheta */
     for (var i = 0; tds.length; i++)
     {
      tds[i].onmousedown = function()
      {
          if( window.getComputedStyle ) {
         bg = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(this, null).backgroundColor;
       } else if( palheta.currentStyle ) {
         bg = document.getElementById(this.id).currentStyle['backgroundColor'];
       }

       document.getElementById('cor').value = bg;
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = bg; /* colore o background do body*/


      }
     }
      
      /*for para segunda palheta*/
      for (var i2 = 0; tds2.length; i++)
      {
        tds2[i].onmousedown = function()
        {
          if( window.getComputedStyle ) {
            bg2 = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(this, null).backgroundColor;
          } else if( palheta2.currentStyle ) {
            bg2 = document.getElementById(this.id).currentStyle['backgroundColor'];
          }
          document.getElementById('cor2').value = bg2;

          $("#div1").css("background-color", bg2); /*colore uma div*/

        }
      }

  }
</script>
```

```css
/*palheta de background*/
#vermelho{
  background-color:red;
}
#verde{
  background-color: green;
}
#amarelo{
  background-color:yellow;
}
#azul{
  background-color:blue;
}
#preto{
  background-color:black;
}


/*palheta da div1*/
#cinza{
  background-color:grey;
}

#rosa{
  background-color:pink;
}

#black{
  background-color:black;
}

#branco{
  background-color:white;
}

#gold{
  background-color:yellow;
}


.cor{
  display:none;
}
 tr td{
   border:1px solid black;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<body>

<table id="palheta">
  <tr>
    <h3> Palheta de cores 1 </h3>
    <td class="td1" id="vermelho"></td>
    <td class="td1" id="azul"></td>
    <td class="td1" id="amarelo"></td>
    <td class="td1" id="preto"></td>
    <td class="td1" id="verde"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" class="cor" name="cor" id="cor" />

<table id="palheta2">
  <tr>
    <h3> Palheta de cores 2 </h3>
    <td class="td2" id="cinza"></td>
    <td class="td2" id="rosa"></td>
    <td class="td2" id="black"></td>
    <td class="td2" id="branco"></td>
    <td class="td2" id="gold"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" class="cor" name="cor2" id="cor2" />


<div id="div1">
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique a inicialização do ciclo.

```
for (var i2 = 0; i2 < tds2.length; i2++)
```

Answer (score 1):

O seu segundo for está utilizando o i do primeiro for.
Utilize o código abaixo:

```
/*for para segunda palheta*/
      for (var j = 0; tds2.length; j++)
      {
        tds2[j].onmousedown = function()
        {
          if( window.getComputedStyle ) {
            bg2 = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(this, null).backgroundColor;
          } else if( palheta2.currentStyle ) {
            bg2 = document.getElementById(this.id).currentStyle['backgroundColor'];
          }
          document.getElementById('cor2').value = bg2;

          $("#div1").css("background-color", bg2); /*colore uma div*/

        }
      }
```